# function gets called automatically and not working as expected

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create an application using React Native. I have a registration page but it does not work.
I have a method called checkPassword to see if the password and verify password the user wrote are the same:

```
checkPassword(){
    console.log("inside checkPassword");
    if (this.state.password == this.state.verify) {
      console.log("inside if check...");
      this.handlePress;
    }else{
      console.log("password not match.");
    }
  }
```

the problem is that in the log I can see that the function is getting called automatically when I get to the registration page. this is the log:

```
RegisterScreen.js:23 inside checkPassword
RegisterScreen.js:25 inside if check...
RegisterScreen.js:23 inside checkPassword
RegisterScreen.js:25 inside if check...
RegisterScreen.js:23 inside checkPassword
RegisterScreen.js:25 inside if check...
```

and it keeps going..

this appears as soon as I get into the register page, plus, this.handlePress not getting called. this is handlePress:

```
 handlePress(){
    firebaseRef.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(newUser){
      //good
      console.log("good")
    }).catch(function(error){
      //bad
      console.log("bad")
    });
  }
```

and here I call the checkPassword function:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.subButtom} onPress={this.checkPassword}>
  <Text style={styles.subTxt}>
  Register
  </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
checkPassword(){
  console.log("inside checkPassword");
  if (this.state.password == this.state.verify) {
    console.log("inside if check...");
    this.handlePress();
  }else{
    console.log("password not match.");
  }
}
```

And try to change the onPress to this too :

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.subButtom} onPress={() => this.checkPassword()}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
checkPassword(){
    console.log("inside checkPassword");
    if (this.state.password == this.state.verify) {
      console.log("inside if check...");
      return this.handlePress();
    }else{
      console.log("password not match.");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but, checkPassword still gets called automatically.